# Regex allow only one dash or only one space

Tags: regex

I want an expression that allows number and one dash OR number and one space. Space or dash are optional.
I tried this

```
/^([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]+(\s[0-9]+)?)$/
```

Accepted regular expressions:

1. 11-222
2. 444 99

Comment: why are you un-happy with your solution?

Comment: i tried this but it doesn't work!

Comment: what is your regex engine? And what do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Does it return unwanted strings? If so, can you make an example? Does it _not_ return wanted strings? If so, can you make an example? Does it print an error message? If so, can you print it? All this information will help you get a much better feedback from this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's explain your regex.

```
  ^                   # beginning of line
    (                   # start group 1
        [0-9]+          # 1 or more digits
        (               # start group 2
            -           # a hyphen
            [0-9]+      # 1 or more digits
        )?              # end group 2, optional
    )                   # end group 1
|                   # OR
    (                   # start group 3
        [0-9]+          # 1 or more digits
        (               # start group 4
            \s          # a space
            [0-9]+      # 1 or more digits
        )?              # end group 4, optional
    )                   # end group 3
  $                   #  end of line
```

The OR acts between the group 1 at the beginning of the line and the group 3 at the end of the line. But you want group 1 and group 3 anchored at the beginning **and** at the end.

Add a group over group 1 and 3:

```
^(([0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)|([0-9]+(\s[0-9]+)?))$
```

You can use non capture groups (more efficient) instead of capture group

```
^(?:(?:[0-9]+(?:-[0-9]+)?)|(?:[0-9]+(?:\s[0-9]+)?))$
```

Combine the hyphen and the space in a character class and remove the superfluous groups:

```
^[0-9]+(?:[-\s][0-9]+)?$
```

If your regex flavour supports it, change the `[0-9]` into `\d`. Finally your regex becomes:

```
^\d+(?:[-\s]\d+)?$
```

Much simpler, no?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the OR in the middle of your expression: `^([0-9]+)(\s|-)([0-9]+)$` works with your examples in Notepad++.

Comment: Thank you! it's working! i just want dash or space to be optional and i made a small change: ^([0-9]+)(\s|-)?([0-9]+)$